# why data descriptors and accessor descriptors can not be used in js an the same time?

Tags: javascript, accessor, descriptor

i am learning 'Object.defineProperty' this method,but i do not understand why data descriptors and accessor descriptors can not  be used   in js an the same time?

Comment: Because it makes no sense. You either create a simple property with provided value (and possibly prevent its modification through `writable: false`), or encapsulate some logic in this property through setters/getters. Can you give an example when you need both? )

Comment: What would you expect a property access to do if there was both a data value and a getter+setter?

Comment: Should we be able to use both at the same time, couldn't we enforce some rules on the value we want to store? For example, we could check that the value is between 0 and 10, or that its type is "number", couldn't we?

Answer (score -2):

`Object.defineProperty` creates **immutable** properties. That's why you can't change them by other descriptors.

However You can configure `defineProperty` descriptors to allow change.
[More on that on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty)